# Firebird build CSV string of 1 field from multiple rows in SQL

Tags: delphi, firebird

In Firebird 2.5 or 3.0, and Delphi 10.2: In a master-detail configuration, where there's always at least 1 and and not more than 4 or 5 detail rows per master, I need to get a single row that has certain fields from the master row and a field that concatenates 1 field from each detail row into a single CSV-format string.  I need to do this all in SQL and not have to create a stored proc or user function, because I need to do this against customer databases and don't want to be adding objects to databases I don't own; I also don't want to use a calculated field in code if I don't have to, because our support guys need to be able to do this by a script in a DB browser rather than building it in into the program.

To model this I'm using the RDB$INDICES and RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS system tables.  Getting one or more rows per index, each with one segments detail field, is straightforward:

```
  SELECT
    r.RDB$INDEX_NAME AS "Index",
    f.RDB$FIELD_POSITION AS "Order",
    f.RDB$FIELD_NAME AS "Fields"
  FROM RDB$INDICES r
    LEFT JOIN RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS f ON r.RDB$INDEX_NAME = f.RDB$INDEX_NAME
  WHERE r.RDB$FOREIGN_KEY IS NULL
  AND UPPER(r.RDB$RELATION_NAME) = UPPER(:TBLNAME)
  ORDER BY r.RDB$RELATION_NAME, f.RDB$FIELD_POSITION
```

But what I need is return one row per index, with "Fields" holding one or more segment names - e.g. run against a table with `SECTIONID` and `KEYID` fields and a compound index on those two fields, the "Fields" column in the above query would hold `SECTIONID,KEYID`.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this short of adding a calculated field that runs a separate query and walks that result set building the string, which seems unnecessarily complex and top-heavy.

Is there a way to do this purely in SQL in Firebird?

Comment: You could try the [`LIST`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs-list) aggregate function, but make sure to read the caveat about order.

Comment: Yep, that's it!  I wasn't aware of that function.  Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 1):

The `LIST()` function is indeed the way to go, but the syntax can be a bit tricky:

```
SELECT
  r.RDB$INDEX_NAME AS "Index",
  CAST((SELECT LIST(TRIM(RDB$FIELD_NAME), ',')
        FROM (SELECT RDB$FIELD_NAME
              FROM RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS
              WHERE RDB$INDEX_NAME = r.RDB$INDEX_NAME
              ORDER BY RDB$FIELD_POSITION)) AS VARCHAR(48)) AS "Fields",
FROM RDB$INDICES r
WHERE r.RDB$FOREIGN_KEY IS NULL
  AND UPPER(r.RDB$RELATION_NAME) = UPPER(':TBLNAME')
ORDER BY r.RDB$RELATION_NAME;
```

The `CAST()` wrapper is just to convert the Fields output from a text blob to simple varchar so that it's readily visible in the SQL browser.  The `TRIM()` function call in the `LIST()` clause is necessary to remove excess whitespace in the output, otherwise you can get a `SECTIONID          ,KEYID` return.

Comment: I would suggest casting to something a bit wider than `VARCHAR(48)`. In Firebird 3 and earlier, object names can be 31 characters and in Firebird 4 63 characters. With two or more columns in an index, it is easy to run out of characters quickly that way.

Comment: Mark, In a general-purpose sense, you're exactly right.  In the case of the DBs that I'll be using this with, a varchar(48) is plenty of space.